# CASE Statement between dates

Tags: mysql, sql, date, case

For my EntryDate column I've been trying to successfully separate my data by month and into specific names '2013_04','2013_05' etc, so I can later group my data by it also. This code has thus far been unsuccessful, how can it be changed to work?

```
CASE
WHEN EntryDate BETWEEN '2013-04-01' AND '2013-04-30' THEN '2013_04'
WHEN EntryDate BETWEEN '2013-05-01' AND '2013-05-31' THEN '2013_05'
WHEN EntryDate BETWEEN '2013-06-01' AND '2013-06-30' THEN '2013_06'
END
```

Thank you.

Comment: If you like, consider following this simple two-step course of action: 1. If you have not already done so, provide proper DDLs (and/or an sqlfiddle) so that we can more easily replicate the problem. 2. If you have not already done so, provide a desired result set that corresponds with the information provided in step 1.

Comment: How isn't it working? Is it mostly working but missing some entries?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `DATE_FORMAT` function:

```
DATE_FORMAT(EntryDate, '%Y_%m')
```

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format

Answer (score 0):

I would use the `year()` and `month()` functions, just because this is common across databases:

```
CONCAT_WS('_', YEAR(EntryDate), MONTH(EntryDate))
```

However, `DATE_FORMAT()` is also a good solution.

Answer (score 0):

DATE_FORMAT() is the best option, but you could use a various number if string functions and CONVERT